# Custom Implicit Type Variable in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to implement a public/global variable so that I can access from any layer(controller/service/dao) of a spring project. For example

```
class Abc{
    public User user;
    public String subdomain;
}
```

Now I want to get user, subdomain values from any layer. But remember that, my project has user management. So I need to specific value for each user session.

**Note:**

- The life cycle of this values is session
- This is not singletone forall users
- This is specific per session

Thanks

Comment: Where do you currently store who the currently logged on user is? Are you using Spring Security? It would help to be more specific.

Comment: Try session scoped beans. Get back to us after trying and describe what went wrong (if anything).

Comment: @trf yes I m using Spring Security.

Comment: @siledh it is not recommended to use session scope in service/dao layer. So anything else so that I can auto inject these values in any layer?

Comment: So maybe your service/dao methods should just accept needed information as parameters?

Comment: are you using any custom spring security authentication provider?

Comment: @siledh no, I want to get properties of Abc class as implicit.

Comment: @DebojitSaikia no, I don't

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to have a service which has the ability to lookup the currently logged on user, and provides the context information you require. As @siledh mentioned, once you have this information, you can then pass it into layers where you do not want to have any concept of context (e.g. in your DOAs)

```
@Service
public class ContextService {
    public User getLoggedOnUser() {
        // Get user id/username from Spring Security principal
        // Use id/username to lookup the User
        // Return the logged on user
    }
}

@Controller
public class SomeController {
    @Autowired
    private ContextService context;
    @Autowired
    private SomeReposity someReposity;

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String homePage() {
        User loggedOn = contextService.getLoggedOnUser();
        String userInformationNeededForHomePage =
             someReposity.findSomethingForUser(loggedOn);
        ...
    }
}

@Repository
public class SomeReposity {
    public String findSomethingForUser(User user) {
        // find something
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to pass User as parameter in Dao layer. I m just looking up something like @Autowire ContextService in SomeRepository Class and other service classes. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. You could inject (using @Autowired) ContextService into you DOA or other services classes (as long as they are Spring managed), though I think the cleaner solution is to not do this - you might want to use your DOAs in situations where there is no logged on user, like in a scheduled task.